# If a small neural network were used as a scoring function for Attention model, what label/value it is trained against?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I am reading up a paper on Attention mechanism of encoder-decoder architecture for machine translation. There were several proposals for the scoring function for decoding step, such as cosine similarity (between an encoder state and a decoder state), simple dot-product, etc... One of them is using a neural network to train to get a score. But what i don't get is what are we going to train it against? By that I mean the output "Y" label/value. The equation for the network is given below.

score(s,h)= v . tanh(W[s;h])

https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/06/24/attention-attention.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neural network that is used for attention is not something that is trained separately. To interpret in simpler words, `tanh(W[s;h])`(what paper mentions as neural net) is a feedforward layer that is trained along with the encoder and decoder together.

Any attention mechanism comes up with a weighting scheme to choose and combine the appropriate encoder states for a particular decoding step. Assume the encoder's output as a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, .., a<sub>n</sub>. For the decoder at every step, a weighted combination of the encoder states is given as input. An attention score gives the appropriate weights α<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>2</sub>, .., α<sub>n</sub> at every decoder step. Hence, say to get a decoder output d<sub>1</sub>, the input would be a<sub>1</sub> * α<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> * α<sub>2</sub> + .. + a<sub>n</sub> * α<sub>n</sub>.

The weights α<sub>1</sub>, .. are obtained by a softmax on the outputs of the attention layer/net, in your case the `tanh`. In this case, the weights of tanh are learned, ie., the backprop and gradient update of tanh is done along with the entire encoder-decoder network.